# How to adjust mobile browser rendering of font sizes uniformly

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm making my website responsive and have started development with the mobile half first.

Browsers render sizes so differently, especially mobile ones.. So all my font sizes aren't set, and the browsers set it themselves. It works great, even the default on an old blackberry.

Problem is, the content of list items within an unordered list doesn't resize.? They stay very small next to the perfectly adjusted text *outside* `<ul>`'s

I've tried using em as my measurement unit, and not only did this not work, it also defeats the point of me making my site dynamic to any browser; I don't want to set a size on anything, especially fonts.

So what can I do to make the font size adjust inside the lists?

Comment: You are overriding your font size somewhere.  This is not normal behavior, and can only be caused by you or some code you imported that is redefining styles.

Comment: Actually Brad, I already tested that.. I removed the css links and hid the files, and guess what? _it didn't do anything_

Comment: Post the code for a reproducible example.  As stated in your question, this should be as simple as `<p>some text</p><ul><li>some list item</li></ul>` which I can guarantee will not reproduce the problem you are seeing, at least on any mobile device I have developed on.

Comment: Yeah literally what you just posted.. the `<ul>` part doesn't work:/ at least for my co-workers' and my phone.

Comment: What devices are you using?  What browser?  What version?

Comment: Can you post an example of code or link to your site?

Comment: http://s1365.photobucket.com/user/jononeil99/media/wp_ss_20130809_0001_zpsc45feeb1.jpg.html  See the `<ul>`?:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />
```

I came across this tag on another question; it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In mobile broswer, you'd better set test-size-adjust to none,

```
body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;}
```

After reset test-size-adjust to none, then try to set other html tags' font-size.